# Method to display UILabels and UIButtons Inline with each Other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

In my app I have a "summary" paragraph that based on data an user actions in the app changes what it displays.  The issue is it displays both regular text and clickable text (like a button) in the same sentence and line. The app will have a series of if else statements and based on the results of these the text that will be displayed is determined, but how do you make some of the text a button tied to an action and some of the text a plain label? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7, buttons look like blue text. I would suggest taking advantage of that fact.

I would use AutoLayout, and create your fields with constraints that put a very small amount of space between each label and button in your line of text/labels, with a vertical constraint on all of them that aligns their leading to match.